# Setting different range of y axis for subplots on the same row (Python, pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am a newbie in python. I am having trouble with setting the range of y values for pyplot.

[image]

As you can see in the image, the y axis is same for the two subplots.

```py
ax[0][0].scatter(x,y,s=2)
ax[0][0].plot(x,model1, 'r')
ax[0][0].set_title('Solution 1')
ax[0][0].set_xlabel('time (s)')
ax[0][0].set_ylabel('Radius of Capillary')
ax[0][0].set_ylim([0,2])

ax[0][1].scatter(x1,d,s=2)
ax[0][1].plot(x,model2, 'r')
ax[0][1].set_title('Solution 2')
ax[0][1].set_xlabel('time (s)')
ax[0][1].set_ylabel('Radius of Capillary')
ax[0][1].set_ylim([0,2.1])
```

I have used this code to adjust the y axis range. However, it seems like I can only adjust range via the second graph, i.e. if I change the y axis for the first graph, it has no effect, while changing the y axis range for the second graph affects both of the graphs. I have used the `set_ylim([])` to adjust.

Thanks.

Comment: Try this ```import numpy as np``` and ```ax[0][1].set_yticks(np.linspace(0, 2.1, 8))```. Also, See the document on [matplotlib.pyplot.set_yticks](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yticks.html)

Comment: Please tell us what you did with a minimal self contained example.